# If I peer into a bag of holding, what do I see?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

For the sake of discussion, assume we are talking about a type IV bag of holding, which can carry up to 250 cubic feet of items. [Source](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/bag-of-holding)

So, let's say I put in a large box the size of, say, a modern refrigerator. Assume the box is light enough for me to be able to put it inside, no problem strength wise.

Then, I place the bag of holding on the floor and hold the opening open. What do I see? Do I see the box (assume I do not put my hand in). If the box is visible, does it appear to be the correct size or shrunken? Do I see it floating in space, or resting on some sort of floor? In either case, what is the color of the surrounding environment. If space, is it blackness? If there's a floor, is it the color of the bag?

Now, say instead of a single item, there are many items inside the bag that fit within the normal rules of the bag. If I peer inside (without sticking my head inside), will I be able to see all the items? Will they apppear stacked on top of each other or separate? If they appear stacked on top of each other, how can I be assured that fragile items will not break? Can fragile items break if I throw the bag across the room?

<sub>If this question contains too many sub questions, please comment and I'd be happy to narrow the scope.</sub>

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Officially, ask the GM

There's no official answers to these questions beyond a couple of [sidelong mentions](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Extradimensional-Spaces), so the DM must answer them if they come up, like, for example, if the party expects to be spending a large amount of time within their [*bag of holding*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/bag-of-holding) (maybe by using a [*bottle of air*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/bottle-of-air) or a [*necklace of adaptation*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/necklace-of-adaptation)).

## Unofficially, here's some speculation

I've speculated below about some things and drawn some conclusions based on the limited information presented by the text about others, but none of these are official, and I'm unaware of an official stance on any of the questions raised.

### Stocking the *bag*

The first problem of shoving a refrigerator-sized box into a [*bag of holding*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/bag-of-holding) is, frankly, *shoving the refrigerator-sized box into it*. The *bag* is only 2 ft. wide and, unless the GM says the *bag* does, that opening *doesn't* stretch to accommodate stuff. So while that opening could accommodate a human child...

[image: Not a refrigerator]

...or a Medium adult, a standard-size kitchen-type refrigerator box would likely be too big.

### Gazing into the *bag*

But let's say that one does get *whatever* into one's *bag of holding* then sets down the *bag* and takes a look inside. What does one see?

A *bag of holding* opens into an extradimensional space in its own demiplane... usually.<sup>1</sup> Whether that demiplane is naturally illuminated or not is up to the DM.

- If a *bag*'s interior is naturally illuminated, can an open *bag* be used for illuminating an area when one's out of torches? Can one enter the *bag*, read by such light, and exit the *bag* if one doesn't exceed the weight limit or overstay the breathable air time limit?
- If the *bag*'s interior is *not* illuminated does one take longer than a full-round action to extract an item from an overloaded *bag*, contrary to the *bag*'s description, because of one's inability to see the *bag*'s contents?

### Reaching into the *bag*

Assuming one can *always* fish items from an unoverloaded<sup>2</sup> *bag* as a move action or from an overloaded *bag* as a full-round action, the magic of the *bag* must keep its contents *sort of* organized, respond to the possessor's will, some DM-determined combination of both, or something entirely different. That's because the *bag* must be more organized and convenient than a backpack: while the move action [retrieve an item](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Move-Actions) provokes attacks of opportunity,

> Retrieving a specific item from a [*bag of holding*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/bag-of-holding) is a move action, unless the *bag* contains more than an ordinary backpack would hold, in which case retrieving a specific item is a full-round action.

So while just as much—if not more—effort is needed to retrieve an item from a *bag of holding*, technically doing so *while threatened* is not as dangerously distracting as retrieving an item from, for example, a backpack.

Thus the DM has *at least* two choices:

1. The possessor of the *bag* looks into the *bag* and sees all the contents as if through a telescope, and is able to manipulate the *bag* opening to see into different parts of the *bag*. If the *bag*'s overloaded, one searches the *bag* with quick glances while keeping an eye on one's foe, I guess.
2. The possessor of the *bag* sees an empty *bag* (or, alternatively, what would be the contents of a normal bag of that size) but can mentally manipulate (perhaps sliding like a touchscreen) objects within the *bag* until the correct one comes into view. This manipulation is rapid but not distracting, so one can keep one's eye on one's foe.

### Stacking stuff in the *bag*

Whether stacked items fall over in the *bag* is the DM's call. For the first kind of *bag* described above, I'd argue *No, the items remain stacked*. That demiplane is stable. However, one must be careful when putting new things into such a *bag* so that they don't crush sensitive items already inside. For the second kind of *bag*, I'd argue *Yes, the stacked items fall.* The second case uses a multiple but limited number of what are, essentially, sub-*bags* within the main *bag* (that number being up to the DM, but likely each as big as a regular bag or, I dunno, like, infinite, each one capable of holding a sling or a piece of chalk).

### Personal experience

The handful of times this has come up, I've used the stable *bag* model, depositing *bag*-stored items on the translucent, illuminated, spongy, gray surface of the *bag*'s own exclusive demiplane. I've never told the PCs that a dense item carelessly tossed into a *bag* (which is, usually, instead, a [*handy haversack*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/bag-handy-haversack)) crushed a fragile item because I figure that when an adventurer tosses treasure into his *bag*, he's careful not to crush *other* treasure while doing so. Some DMs might not be so kind. But, then again, I've also never had PCs stack a series of items on top of one another in an effort to shortcut the expected time to to extract a lone item from the *bag*. That might change my mind (or, at least, see their foes start doing the same).

---

<sup>**1**</sup> The *Knights of the Dinner Table* comic book illustrates plots that may develop in a campaign wherein *bags of holding* share a demiplane in [*The Bag Wars Saga*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1594591148).
<sup>**2**</sup> Not a real word.

Comment: [Underload](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/underload) however, is a real word and means exactly what you want to convey... XD

Answer (score 2):

I’ve always had it that items placed inside a bag of holding disappear into it and are no longer affected by “normal” laws of physics. Items in a bag of holding do not interact with each other, unless something sentient is in the bag it would be able to interact with other items as if they were reaching in. Basically all the items are in the same place in a sort of state of flux(if that makes any sense) up to the weight/volume limit of the bag(no organization required). The bag would reacts to your thoughts bringing the desired item to your hand, and if someone doesn’t know what is inside a bag of holding reaches inside a random item would come to their hand. Looking inside is just a void.

Answer (score 1):

"When you peer into the Bag of Holding, you experience an intense feeling of vertigo.  Save to avoid adding the remains of your last meal to its contents."

In the games that I run, the interior of a BoH is not a 5x5x10-foot space or anything of the sort.  The interior, as stated in the SRD link from the question, is not just extradimensional, it is *non*-dimensional.  It has no height or length or depth, but is utterly foreign to how we perceive the world around us, because it does not share the structure of that world.  "Stacking" items within the Bag is similarly meaningless - how can one thing be on top of another when "on top of" isn't a well-defined concept?

Rather than being arranged spatially, all of the items in a BoH are simply *inside* and, when you reach in, your hand closes on one of them<sup>1</sup>.  If the Bag holds less than a backpack could contain, then you usually get the one you want on the first try (move action), otherwise it might take a moment to get the right one (full-round action).

---

<sup>1</sup> If you want to get pseudoscientific about it, you could say that it holds a quantum superposition of all items placed within, which collapses into a single object when you reach inside.  But that's a horrible abuse of the concepts of quantum mechanics.

Comment: Yes, but joking aside, what DO you see?

Comment: You see a non-dimenstional space. Our brains and sensory apparatus are evolved to deal with *three*-dimensional spaces, not *non*-dimensional spaces, and are unable to process it.