# Can a human being fit inside of a bag of holding?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

Can a human fit inside of a bag of holding?
Pathfinder says that:

> This appears to be a common cloth sack about 2 feet by 4 feet in size

Is that 2×4 feet in opening area or size of the bag?

Comment: Well, depends... a *whole* human?  :)

Comment: [(See picture.)](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/65638/8610)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pessimistic case is that the opening of the bag is around 2' (~60 cm) long when the bag is laid flat; this gives a circumference of around 120 cm.

Human shoulder width, based on quick googling, seems to be around 50 cm (less for people who don't do strength training). This means that a human could be 10 cm deep and still fit in comfortably (without clothes). Chest circumference for men might be around 105 cm, just to sanity check the number above.

This means that most adventurers won't fit in very well, especially if they have gear on.

The escape artist check to move through a tight space, defined as one where your head fits but shoulders do not, is DC 30 and one check takes a minute. If you start doing this legs first, you should be capable of taking 20 without suffocating. A reasonable GM might even want to lower the DC, since the shoulders almost fit in and the container is flexible; personally, I'd rule that a small amount of wiggling would be required and use an escape artist DC around 10-20; difficult with armour or gear, possible otherwise.

RAW, **fitting in should be possible at least with a DC 30 escape artist check.**

Answer (score 2):

#### With Some Effort You Could Stuff Them In

The opening circumference is 4'. Per conversations on [the Paizo board](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2mihh?Bag-of-Holding-Opening-Size), the diameter of the opening is ~15 inch diameter hole. I suppose it depends on the size of the person, but if I were DM I'd say with enough time and/or cooperation, they could wriggle into it.

But to quote [the wiki](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/bag-of-holding):

> If living creatures are placed within the bag, they can survive for
> up to 10 minutes, after which time they suffocate.

Comment: That sadly dosen't give an answer but an indiaction

Comment: Perhaps I should have been clearer. As a sack of that size, you should be able to fit them in, though it may be tight. However, once you do....

Comment: "you should be able to fit them in" Sorry, that sounds like an opinion and I need a hard yes or no, preferebly by the books or some Q & A

Comment: I mean... there are other discussions:
http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2mihh?Bag-of-Holding-Opening-Size

But my take away is, if you try hard, you could probably get them in.

Comment: is that guy an official pathfinder employee?

Comment: Beat me to the diameter point. I was curious to know shoulder width as that might be the biggest hang up in stuffing a person in a bag. I found the average human male shoulder with is 17-18ins. Given that the bag wouldn't need to be the perfect circle to get the shoulders in and the person balled up a little. I think definitely a person could be stuffed into a bag.

Comment: No it's not official. It's hard to give a stronger answer other than maybe because because a 7' human barbarian probably has massive shoulders... but a slender 5'5" human wizard might have small shoulders... so I say let the DM decide.

Comment: @KumosAgosta MUWAHAHAHA

Comment: 2x4 isn't the opening but the size of the bag

Comment: Yes. So, picture the bag laid flat. The top is 2', the length 4'. That means the opening is 4' in circumference...

Comment: 2x4 meaning that its 2 wide across and 4 in lenght. Meanning the top is max 2' in diameter

Comment: Yes. So it comes down to, how big are the shoulders? Or I suppose if they're overweight it could be how big their belly is?